# please explain the List functionality during retrieving from this way

Tags: java, dictionary

I have one `List<Map<String, String>> first_list` and `Map<String, String> second_list`.Whenever i try to retrieve the value from `first_list` to second list(map).  I am getting the last value present in the `first_list`.

My code is:

Where a1,a2,a3 contain some column data from table
ex:
a1:{name,age,dob,..}

```
List<Map<String, String>> first_list={"a1","a2","a3"}// example
for (Map<String, String> second_list: firstList) {
String name = second_list.get("name");
}
```

please guide me.Thanks in advance

Comment: You overwrite the variable name in each iteration so that after you leave the for-loop the value of the last element is stored in "name".

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achive with your code? What is the goal?

Comment: I want to get the  three names from the list..but wat acutally happening is getting last value alone..@Patrick

Comment: Now,I declared the String name as global variable, but it showing the same thing..@ Joachim Rohde..

Comment: A global variable doesn't change anything, you still overwrite the value. Either you store the names in a list or process the name directly within the for-loop. Also take a look at popalka's answer to get an understanding what you are doing there.

Comment: ok..thanqu buddy..

Answer (score 1):

May be some well-compiled code will help to understand your code behavior

```
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    Map<String,String> a1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,String> a2 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,String> a3 = new HashMap<>();
    a1.put("name", "a1");
    a2.put("name", "a2");
    a3.put("name", "a3");
    List<Map<String, String>> first_list= Arrays.asList(a1,a2,a3);
    for (Map<String, String> second_list: first_list) {
        String name = second_list.get("name");
        System.out.println("name = " + name);
    }

}
```

Will output

```
name = a1
name = a2
name = a3
```

Comment: Buddy I am not using arrays.please guide me through list,

Comment: List<Map<String, String>> first_list={a1,a2,a3}, where a1,a2,a3 is not variable ,its object .Each one contain like this..                                       Ex:a1{name:apple,age:10;size:8},a2{name:grape,age:12;size:5}...  now guide from here

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comment:

> List> first_list={a1,a2,a3}, where a1,a2,a3 is not variable ,its object .Each one contain like this.. Ex:a1{name:apple,age:10;size:8},a2{name:grape,age:12;size:5}...

I dont understand why you have implement a complex scenario using List of Maps. And to be honest I do not understand your question.

But anyhow, I just want to guide you to another solution which I would prefer. Instead using a `Map<String, String>` just create an Object `Fruits`.

```
public class Fruit {

        private String name;
        private int age;
        private int size;

        public Fruit(String name, int age, int size) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.size = size;
        }
        //getter and setter
```

I dont know from where you get the data inside your maps, but they have to come from anywhere. If you then just give those values in your new Fruit Object:

```
Fruit fruitApple = new Fruit("apple", 10, 8);
Fruit fruitGrape = new Fruit("grape", 12, 5);
```

You are able to put those in a `List<Fruit>` of Fruits.

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
fruits.add(fruitApple);
fruits.add(fruitGrape);
```

And then you can iterate ofer the List.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fruit fruitApple = new Fruit("apple", 10, 8);
        Fruit fruitGrape = new Fruit("grape", 12, 5);

        List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
        fruits.add(fruitApple);
        fruits.add(fruitGrape);

        for(Fruit fruit : fruits){
            System.out.println("name: " + fruit.getName());
        }
    }
```

output:

```
name: apple
name: grape
```

Its an easy implementation and easy to understand.

Comment: @Rangith if you like the answer just accept or/and upvote.

Comment: @partrick ,I did that.But it showing you need 15 reputation to vote up.I have only 11 reputation

Comment: @Rangith try it again ;) but accepting an answer is always possible, or not?